# How to add Time info to GeoTiff served from Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff

I have a geotiff file (somedata.tif) that I want to serve from geoserver wms associated with the time 10/22/2010 12:00:00.

I'm currently using a geoserver raster data source of type GeoTiff pointed to somedata.tif with a layer pointed at that data source.  Using this configuration, I can successfully serve the image, with no time information.

I'm looking for functionality that would be similar to mapserver where I set wms_timedefault=10/22/2010 12:00:00.

My desired end result is an http header like this:

```
Warning: 99 Nearest value used: TIME=2010-10-22T12:00Z
```

Can I add time information to a Geotiff data source in geoserver v2.0.2?  Does it belong in somedata.tif? Does it belong in my source or layer configurations?

My GIS vocabulary isn't 100% so if I need to clarify anything, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research.  Geoserver does not currently support queries based on Time where Time is set to use nearestValue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you add the time to it. This http://geo-solutions.blogspot.com/2009/12/adding-time-support-to-geoserver-and.html blog entry seems to indicate it works it out from the file name so maybe change somedata.tif to somedata-20101022.tif?